# How can an application be rewritten in machine code and interfaced with Java?

Tags: java, machine-code

I was reading [The Java Language Environment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/langenv-140151.html). In the [High Performance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/intro-141325.html#1751) section I found this block

> Applications requiring large amounts of compute power can be designed such that compute-intensive sections can be rewritten in native machine code as required and interfaced with the Java platform.

I didn't get it in fact, so how can an application be written in native machine code and interfaced with the Java platform?

Comment: You might find this helpful. https://ostendorf.com/2012/11/java-native  This JIT already turns Java code into native machine code,so it is rare that doing this will help, unless you use special instructions Java doesn't utilise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to interface with native code.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure this is really what you want/need. Modern JVM offers a lot of performances in terms of Java code optimization, so "simple" Java is often enough.

JNI is powerful, but it brings a lot of headaches ...

Comment: I'm currently reading about this. I was not able to imagine how an application can be written in native machine code and interfaced with Java.

Comment: It works fine actually. We do that a lot at my work. But as I said, it brings a lot of headaches and make you loose a lot of Java advantages such as portability.